# What are the differences between Pentax weather sealings - DA★, WR, AW?

Tags: lens, pentax, weather-sealing

Pentax has in current product line weather-sealed lenses with three different markings -

- DA★ on primes and fast zooms;
- WR on consumer zooms and 100mm macro;
- AW on some newer primes.

What are the reasons to use different notations for weather sealings? Are there any significant differences in their protection, expected lifetime etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DA* are top-of-the-line Pentax lenses. According to Pentax, they are the best lenses ever made and they include weather-resistance but the DA* label means a lot more, including ultra-sonic motor and a commitment to excellent quality.

AW label introduced for DSLRs along with the [DA 560mm F/5.6 ED AW](http://www.neocamera.com/lens/pentax/da_560mm_f5.6_ed_aw). It is also used to designate weather-sealed lenses for digital medium-format cameras. According to Pentax again, this signifies a new improved class of weather-resistant lenses which are also high quality.

WR is the basic Weather-Resistance label and implies nothing more than a weather-resistant lens.

Comment: Several AW lenses for 645 system were introduced already before the 560mm/5.6.

Comment: Thanks! Edited. Forgot about the 645D considering it's above my budget.